# Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException The payload is invalid

Tags: laravel, encryption

I am new to laravel. This is an existing project. I saw this error on one page. I did not know how to solve it. I google it but did not find a solution so I wrote here.

When I open a page, it shows this error.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I remove this line and everything working fine : <td>{{(Crypt::decrypt($user->password))}}</td>. I dont understand this.

Answer (score 0):

This means that a value is transmitted that cannot be deciphered. Maybe you are using a database dump, or you have changed the application key, or you have an error when saving the data

Comment: I printr $payload. I got this data : Array ( 
[iv] => B2maaqF1Dp+WbL0rkqL1Ww== 
[value] => 8Sy26rfdwUvhSs8NoZqZSZO60VMq9UkvCcOsGMaQHWWLRVKfUs/KnSJbzq/BWTGMHxdWhLl4zd7VRPapsg+bCZ3qrXaOzyKLF/P/i0a1H//qE3Zfv97VQG9ZDynVcA8w 
[mac] => b0457cd083b8a824c772d99b32daffcc2bdb2d3b234933987137896a06e907b8 
) 
Array ( 
[iv] => XQPo7TDQvn7G8YJitkc/+w== 
[value] => htS9qciB/vKtiGPcKKrDwnHq0L4nTZrntoZbd9iXttiLKtmwPw3frWVyettGt6wZhvFbl7t9XDRgdvmwg6GmrLICdCXvI7qpyEcI1F/7/PdZP5IcRcaDKJPNJ1d9p0E9 
[mac] => 470bbc864a10da5c2dad706c7b0e46337dde23827d893d3c6e7843ceeb301134 
)

Comment: payload must be a string. How we got the array?

Comment: I print it like this: protected function validPayload($payload){ print_r($payload); } I commented return code.

Comment: I remove this line and everything working fine  : <td>{{(Crypt::decrypt($user->password))}}</td>. I dont understand this.